# How to add multiple div inside single div with horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to add multiple div inside a single div with horizontal scroll.

**This is my code:**

```
  <div id="scrollimages">
        <script>
            var container = document.getElementById("scrollimages");
            var array=["img/screen2.png","img/logo.png"];
            for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            {
                var src="url("+array[i]+")";
//                var inside = '<div class="block" style="background-image: { ' + src + ' }"></div>';
                var inside = '<div class="blocks"></div>'
                inside.style.backgroundImage=src;
                inside.style.marginLeft=100*i+"%";
                container.innerHTML +=inside;


            }

            </script>
        </div>
```

**This is my css code:**

```
#scrollimages {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
     white-space:normal;
    overflow-y:none;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.blocks
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
    margin-left:0px;
    word-wrap:normal;
}
```

First time i am using java script and css all ,so i can't get this easy step .help me out this problem.

what mistake i made,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same `#id` can only be once in a document.

```
var inside = '<div id="block"></div>'
```

Use a class instead

```
var inside = '<div class="block"></div>'
```

and in CSS

```
.block { ...
```

Also, much easier, to add the attributes directly to the string

```
var inside = '<div class="block" style="background-image:'+ src +'"></div>';
```

Edit: fixed remove {} in `style`.

**Edit:** There were some other problems in the script, here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/C14L/9hnqheos/

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/wDRHphNextb6bZfpZvv7Pp i have edited as per your suggestion but not working

Comment: Added a jsfiddle to my answer.

Comment: that is my requirement help me out @C14l

Answer (score 0):

Add Flex property to the container, also keep overflow auto. If using Flex no need to use white-space.

```
#scrollimages {
display: flex;  
overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching background to `div` I am creating `img` & appending it inside the div.

Also

Hope this will be useful

**JS**

```
var container = document.getElementById("scrollimages");
var myArray=[image urls];
for(var i=0;i < myArray.length;i++){
var _createElem = document.createElement('div');
var _img = document.createElement('img')
_img.src = myArray[i]
 _createElem.id ="block_"+i;
_createElem.appendChild(_img)
_createElem.className = "block";
container.appendChild(_createElem);
}
```

**CSS**

```
#scrollimages {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    margin-top:20px;

}
.block{
    width:auto;
    display:table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}
```

you can make further changes if it required

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hn0gnp7d/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As per C14L, need to assign class, and since you're using getElementByID, each element should be assigned a seperate ID.

In the below JS Fiddle, I've swapped backgroundImage for backgroundColor, and removed your margin code (not sure what you were attempted here, but you had 100% margin on the 2nd iteration, 200% for the third...  Don't think thats what you had in mind...  For demo purposes, height of 'block' was set to 30px instead of 100% since divs have no height by default...

https://jsfiddle.net/7mua0rez/

```
var container = document.getElementById("scrollimages");
var array=["red","green", "black"];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
  var src=array[i];
  var inside = '<div id="block' + i + '" class="block"></div>'

    container.innerHTML +=inside;

  document.getElementById("block" + i).style.backgroundColor=src;
  document.getElementById("block" +i).style.marginLeft=10+"%";
}
```